Has there ever been a comprehensive audit of voter eligibility and identity in a U.S. election?
I'm well aware that there have been numerous recounts in U.S. elections (most notably the 2000 recount in Florida). They sometimes find small discrepancies from non-malicious human errors but otherwise show that votes are being counted accurately. However, recounts can only validate vote counting accuracy - they cannot check whether the votes themselves were legitimate.
Have there been any comprehensive, large-scale audits that checked other sources of possible fraud? Specifically:

Voter qualification: Confirming each voter's citizenship and residency status at the time of the election
Ballot authenticity: Ensuring voters cast their own ballots, including checking if each voter was alive on Election Day, their identity wasn't misused, and their mail ballot wasn't submitted by others without permission
Assisted voting integrity: Checking whether those requiring assistance could select their preferred candidate without improper influence

Has such an audit been completed in recent decades? If multiple such audits have been completed, what was the largest election (by votes cast) to undergo this scrutiny? I'll also accept answers covering audits that used random sampling or other optimizations rather than checking every single vote.
Update from Nov 1st: Reports from routine voter roll maintenance or voters list purges would qualify if thoroughly documented. Here's a purely hypothetical example of the kinds of checks and findings such a pre-voting report might include:



Check Type
% of Total
Check Type
% of Total




Total Registered Voters
100%
Birth Date Mismatch with SSA
1.24%


Address Has >8 Voters
0.82%
Multiple State Registrations
2.15%


Commercial Zone Listed as Residence
0.31%
Failed Citizenship Check
0.08%


Deceased Voter Match
0.67%
Referred for Investigation
0.007%



Such an audit would need to detail its complete methodology, databases used (SSA, DHS, DMV, etc.), how their verification processes work, how they've been improving it over the years, etc.

Answering a follow-up question from the comments:

How many occurrences of significant fraud have been observed in other high-functioning Western democracies in the last century or so?


In 2005, there were credible reports of electoral fraud involving postal voting in Birmingham, UK
In 2011, a voter suppression scandal occurred in Canada, where the election in Etobicoke Centre (Ontario) was decided by a 26-vote margin. Allegedly, 181 voters were improperly allowed to vote, but the Canadian Supreme Court upheld the result in a split 4-3 decision
The 2016 Austrian Presidential election was annulled and re-run due to irregularities, particularly with postal votes

And some U.S. examples for the sake of completeness:

The 1982 Illinois State Senate Primary saw numerous instances of fraud, with a grand jury finding approximately 100,000 fraudulent votes cast in Chicago. Fifty-eight election officials were convicted of various election-related offenses
The 1997 Miami mayoral election was annulled due to absentee ballot fraud
The 2003 East Chicago mayoral Democratic primary was overturned because of absentee ballot fraud
The 2018 North Carolina's 9th Congressional District election was annulled due to illegal ballot harvesting and ballot tampering


I think you're somewhat misusing terms here. Risk-limiting audits are conducted for some US elections. Typically these involve checking if a sample of the ballots were counted properly (as opposed to a recount, where the whole lot would be counted again).

While the phrase "postelection audit" can be used to mean a variety of election validation efforts, as a term of art it refers to checking paper ballots (or records) against the results produced by the vote tallying equipment to ensure accuracy.

Some details:

A total of 49 states conduct some type of post-election audit. Alabama does not require post-election audits but piloted different audit types in the 2022 election.
The most common type is a “traditional” post-election tabulation audit. There are also risk-limiting audits (RLAs), procedural audits, and audits that states conduct after an election that do not fall into either of these categories. More details on each type of audit are found below, but in summary:

35 states and Washington, D.C., require a traditional post-election tabulation audit: Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Connecticut, Delaware, Florida, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Iowa, Ohio, Oregon, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana (upon implementation of a new voting system), Maryland, Massachusetts, Minnesota, Missouri, Montana, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina, Pennsylvania, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Washington, West Virginia, Wisconsin and Wyoming.
Of these, Ohio, Oregon and Washington give counties the option of conducting a risk-limiting audit instead and Indiana, Kentucky, Michigan, New Jersey, Pennsylvania and Texas, have had pilot programs to conduct risk-limiting audits.

Six states have a statutory requirement for a risk-limiting audit: Georgia, Colorado, Maine, (pilot in 2024 and statewide in 2025), Nevada, Rhode Island, and Virginia.

Eight states have other post-election audits that do not fall into the categories above:

Indiana (procedural and/or traditional post-election audits may be authorized under some circumstances, with a pilot for RLAs)
Michigan (traditional is authorized but not required, procedural audit, and had a pilot program for an RLA in 2020)
Mississippi (procedural audit)
Nebraska (not required but may be requested by the secretary of state)
New Hampshire (randomized audit of ballot counting devices)
North Dakota (post-election logic and accuracy test)
Oklahoma (traditional is authorized but not required)
South Carolina (data comparison)



Traditional post-election tabulation audits are the most common audit type and look at a fixed percentage of voting districts or voting machines and compare the paper record to the results produced by the voting system. Even in a landslide election, they will count the same number of ballots as they would in a nail-biter election. Traditional post-election tabulation audits are usually conducted manually by hand-counting a portion of the paper records and comparing them to the electronic results produced by an electronic voting machine.
In recent years, researchers have developed statistically based audit techniques that decrease the number of ballots to be audited, while also providing statistical confidence that the election result is correct. This method checks a sample of ballots (or voter verifiable records) that is guaranteed to have a large, pre-specified chance of correcting the reported outcome if the reported outcome is wrong (that is, if a full hand count would reveal an outcome different from the reported outcome). As defined in Washington, "a 'risk-limiting audit' means an audit protocol that uses statistical principles and methods and is designed to limit the risk of certifying an incorrect election outcome." In races with a large margin, fewer ballots need to be counted. If the race is tighter, more ballots are audited.
States may have a process for ensuring the correct process and procedures were followed during the course of the election. This is referred to as a “procedural audit” and may be conducted instead of or in addition to a post-election tabulation audit. Procedural audits vary in their scope and comprehensiveness, but almost always include a ballot accounting and reconciliation process.
In 2023, Utah passed a law requiring biennial procedural audits in addition to their traditional audit. The procedural audit is conducted by the Legislative Auditor General and may include auditing voter registration processes, candidate filing, ballot preparation and more.

As you can see, checking the eligibility of the voters after they cast their votes is seldom done as part of these audits, although perhaps Utah wants to change that.
I managed to find what Utah enacted (wrt voters' audit):

(2) The audit shall include:
(a) a random selection of at least .02% of the active registered voters statewide
(b) at least one active registered voter from each county.
(3) For each voter selected for the audit, the auditor shall:
(a) verify that the voter is eligible for registration;
(b) verify that the voter's registration information is accurate and supported by the documentation on file;
(c) verify that there is a signature on file for the voter;
(d) check for duplicate voter registrations; and
(e) search available resources to determine whether the voter is deceased.

So, the mandatory sampled percentage in each audit is pretty low (0.02%). N.B. it's officially called a "voter registration audit". TBH, IDK how it's different from the "purges" you've mentioned other than by name, and perhaps periodicity. Actually, the Utah audit doesn't seem to mandate removing somebody from the rolls. Just that the audit need result in a report identifying areas of concern. But presumably removing ineligible entries could be a follow-up action. So I guess that's the difference between an audit and a purge. So, states which conduct regular purges, and in which citizens need to re-prove their citizenship, implicity do such (voter as opposed to vote) audits.
By the way, most of your examples don't pertain to elections annulled because of unqualified voters, but rather due to other kinds of irregularities/fraud.

As for the Canadian example, it's somewhat less clear than you make it. The first instance appeal was successful on the grounds that records of voter eligibility were lost or misplaced by the state. It wasn't actually proven in court those people were not actually eligible to vote. So the Supreme Court erred on the side of not disqualifying votes because of a possible clerical error on behalf of (temp) state employees.
In the US, non-citizen residents who register to vote are sometimes prosecuted. I'm not aware of an election where the (proven) number of these was high enough to change a result. The DA statement even stuff like:

Noncitizen voting is an extremely isolated and rare event. Investigations in multiple states and nationwide have found no evidence of large numbers of noncitizens registering to vote. Even less common is a noncitizen actually casting a ballot.

Conversely:

Election officials must be careful not to mistakenly remove eligible voters from voter rolls, since some databases may be outdated and may not show if an immigrant has become a naturalized citizen. Such errors resulted in large numbers of eligible citizens wrongly flagged for removal in Texas in 2019. [...]
After the 2016 election, the Brennan Center for Justice, which advocates for voting rights, surveyed local election officials in 42 jurisdictions with high immigrant populations and found just 30 cases of suspected noncitizens voting out of 23.5 million votes cast, or 0.0001%. [...]
While the conservative Heritage Foundation has actively promoted claims about the risk of noncitizens voting this campaign season, its own data suggests how rare these cases are. The Washington Post reviewed a Heritage database of voter fraud cases and found 85 cases relating to allegations of noncitizens voting between 2002 and 2023. [...] That analysis found only 10 cases involving undocumented immigrants since the 1980s. Heritage has said the database is just a sampling of fraud cases and is not comprehensive.
Georgia Secretary of State Brad Raffensperger launched an audit in 2022 that found over the previous 25 years, fewer than 1,700 people believed to be noncitizens had attempted to register to vote. None were able to cast ballots.

The last bit refers to 2020 only. It is claimed a few [may] have voted before:

Georgia’s top elections official said Wednesday that a check of voter rolls found that 20 of the 8.2 million people registered to vote in the state are not U.S. citizens.
Secretary of State Brad Raffensperger said during a news conference that the voter registrations for those people had been canceled and that they will be referred to local prosecutors for potential criminal charges. His office said none of those people has cast a ballot in November’s general election, but nine of the 20 had voted in previous elections and the other 11 had no record of voting.
Additionally, there are 156 people whose citizenship status requires additional investigation and his office has opened case files for those individuals, Raffensperger said.

TBH, if I'm not misreading that piece, the claim of non-citizenship appears to be based mainly on the fact that they "had filled out a sworn statement saying they were not citizens to get out of jury duty". As this is a recent announcement, we'll see how the actual prosecutions turn out. (From another survey, about 9% of Americans apparently claim to have lied to get out of jury duty. The vast majority of these gave other reasons than non-citizenship though.)
BTW, it's been alleged that the Georgia voter audit in some cases violated their own guidelines that require someone to have affirmed somewhere they're non-citizen after voting, but in some cases a voter's affirmation prior to the election was used as "proof" of non-citizenship (so even if they could have acquired it in the meantime, which some say they did).
There have also been some controversial surveys that (simply) asked respondents if they were non-citizen and have voted. The results of these have been contested on the grounds of respondent carelessness, i.e. margin of error in surveys.
The latter is probably (the two or three kinds of) data being called an "investigation" but they're clearly not election audits, nor does it make a lot of sense to call them that.
Also, regarding purges, the decision to not vote is often used a trigger.

TL;DR: No, such audits have never been conducted? Ok, I’ll accept that too, just perhaps needs a more clear “No” statement.

@JonathanReez The recent Georgia "audit" in principle tested whether ineligible voters had registered. But the slim details don't suggest the criteria were entirely robust. Of course, state incompetence at the registration stage (where automatic checking of status should happen) is also known. Florida famously tried to prosecute ex-felons for voting when they had been allowed to register (after a rule change on felon voting) after checks on their voting rights during registration.

Elections are expensive and funding is limited. I don't see much motivation for a given state to arbitrarily budget extra money for an after-the-fact audit above and beyond the existing audits and cross-checks.
In other words, if you have an extra million to spend on election integrity, do you spend it before or after the election?

@matt_black yeah finding out details on criteria used in validating voters at the registration stage is insanely difficult. I suspect the real answer is 'nothing is checked' which is why no one wants to talk about it.

@JonathanReez while it might be hard to find the details (especially when they are local rules, not national rules), it doesn't mean checking eligibility is hard. That is why there are many reports of voters being removed or rejected.

Impromptu Audits are Occurring Right Now
Alabama recently purged a bunch of "suspicious" voters from it's rolls, which a judge recently reversed because it was done too close to the election.
Of the 3,000+ people removed, nearly 2,000 had already proven that they were qualified to vote, and 159 were removed from the rolls.
The 159 weren't Necessarily Fraud
None of the reporting I've seen has given a breakdown of why people removed from the rolls, but presumably most of them had simply moved out of the state. There is a bipartisan, independent organization that coordinates between the states to identify voters who have moved, but several states have chosen to make their rolls less up-to-date by pulling out of the service.
Voter Qualification Seems Solid
So if out of ~5,000,000 Alabamans, there were ~160 people who could have potentially voted while not qualified, I'd say the system appears to be working pretty well. These impromptu audits (VA is "running" one as well) seem to show that only qualified voters are voting. (Which makes sense, voter roll maintenance is one of the normal activities that voting officials do when they aren't running active elections.)
Ballot Authenticity is Ensured by the Voter
Voters can check the status of their mail-in / absentee ballot online, so if someone acquires their ballot and votes with it, the voter can determine this and inform voting officials.
Assisted Voting Integrity is Also Ensured by the Voter
If the voter does not trust someone to help them, they should not select that person to help them vote.

Did Alabama explain how they've flagged those 3,000 people? I'd want a very detailed breakdown of every single step they've completed to figure out potential non-citizens.

@JonathanReez per the article, the ~3k people were identified because they had used a foreign national number on both unemployment benefits and drivers license applications. Non-citizens receive a ITIN which is only replaced by a SSN after becoming a citizen.

@EllisValentiner "Non-citizens receive a ITIN which is only replaced by a SSN after becoming a citizen": that is absolutely not correct.  Everyone who is authorized to work in the US gets a SSN, including green card holders, H-1B workers, students, and the like.  On top of that, a good many people who aren't authorized to work can get SSNs for various purposes; they receive a card with the text "not valid for employment without DHS authorization" or something along those lines.  In fact, I believe JonathanReez has personal experience of this.

@phoog - there's going to be two general cases here; authorized immigrants (who would have an SSN) and not-authorized immigrants (who would have an ITIN to pay taxes, but NOT an SSN) -- so the Alabama action was specifically targeting "illegals", even though green card holders wouldn't be able to legally vote in a federal election either

For what it's worth, the recent VA voter purge was equally... unsophisticated. They purged everyone who had failed to check the "I'm a US citizen" box on a DMV form; even those who had previously checked the box on other forms, and knowing that the check box was in an unusual place that was likely to be missed. It's highly likely that a super-majority of the purged VA voters are in fact US citizens and eligible voters.

@codeMonkey the Alabama purge has nothing to do with SSNs or ITINs and had nothing to do with illegal immigrants.  The "foreign national numbers" are the A-numbers issued by the Department of Homeland Security or its predecessor, the Immigration and Naturalization Service.  There were no illegals; the majority of the people identified were formerly green card holders who had in the meanwhile been naturalized.

@JonathanReez according to the court documents, they flagged people who applied for "foreign national" driver's licenses and therefore had disclosed their "A number" in the application, they also flagged people who had an A number associated with a claim for unemployment benefits, and they flagged people who were recorded as having checked a box indicating noncitizen status, which explains why some natural-born citizens were included, though it's not clear whether this was because they'd checked the box in error or had been recorded as having checked the box when they hadn't checked it.



Voter qualification: Confirming each voter's citizenship and residency status at the time of the election
Ballot authenticity: Ensuring voters cast their own ballots, including checking if each voter was alive on Election Day, their identity wasn't misused, and their mail ballot wasn't submitted by others without permission
Assisted voting integrity: Checking whether those requiring assistance could select their preferred candidate without improper influence


Caveat: As elections are administered at the state level, likewise all of these criteria are administered at the state level, not at the Federal level. In fact, in many states, they are further delegated to the county / local level. As such, there is not a single, universal answer for the entire United States, or even necessarily within any specific state.
Among these criteria, the first two are routinely examined with every election. For example, the state of Indiana just recently asked the Federal government for citizenship verification for over 100,000 people who had registered without showing government-issued ID. However, note that they - the state - must request this information; there's not a central Federal database, to which states have ready access, that returns this information with a simple query.
States also routinely purge their voter rolls based on other data such as tax returns, driver's licenses, etc.
When it comes to ballot authenticity, the typical system is that mail-in ballots are returned in a sealed envelope with the voter's information - including signature - on the outside envelope. This information is verified, and then the ballot is removed and added, unopened, to the collection of valid ballots. If there are questions, the outer envelope is instead set aside for more detailed scrutiny.
Some of the items verified during this stage:

If relevant, did the voter request a mail-in ballot? (some states send a ballot to every registered voter, while others require a request - with or without reason - before a ballot is sent out)
Has a ballot already been received for this voter?
Does the voter's information, including signature, match their registration?
Is the ballot / envelope genuine?

At that point, once accepted, the ballot is disconnected from the outside envelope, ensuring the voter's privacy - no one can know which ballot was theirs, or therefore who they voted for.
There is some nuance, here, however:

Whenever ballots are mailed in ahead of election day, there is some level of "risk" (if you will) that a voter has deceased between returning their ballot and election day. It is unlikely that the state can verify the aliveness of every voter on election day, and even more unlikely that, even if they somehow knew that a particular voter was deceased, they could do anything about it. (Since, once the ballot is accepted and added to the pool, there's no way to rewind this.)

This is considered an acceptable risk, since the voter was presumably alive when they cast their ballot. It would be no different from someone voting in person on election day, then dying in a car accident on their way home - they were alive when the vote was cast, whether or not they were by the time polls closed.


Some of the persons caught committing voter fraud were caught by this type of audit - such as when signatures did not match or where someone pre-deceased the delivery of ballots but one was returned in their name anyway. Because of the lead-time involved in printing and mailing ballots to registered voters, there's always some "risk" that a ballot will be sent to someone who is no longer alive.
Another example of voter fraud for which people have been prosecuted is where they cast a mail-in ballot and then attempted to vote in person. How this is handled - or even detected - will vary widely by state so there's not a universal solution.

If the state maintains proper records, the polling place would know that the person had requested / received a mail-in ballot, or possibly even that the ballot had been returned.
If the ballot has not been returned (or, for example, if the person claimed not to have received it), they might be given an opportunity to cast a provisional ballot. These would be set aside until the rest of the ballots are processed and, if a mail-in ballot is received, the provisional is discarded - or possibly kept as evidence for a fraud case.



Regarding "assisted voting integrity", unfortunately, there's not much able to be audited here. If votes are cast in person, obviously, poll workers can monitor things. However, with remotely-cast votes, nobody else can see what's going on at the time the vote was cast. I believe some states request attestation that the ballot was not coerced or influenced, but this is not universally true.

Are poll workers really allowed to go into the booth to monitor the interaction between the voter and their assistant, to ensure that the assistant is acting in accordance with the voter's instructions?

@Barmar Many locations don't even have the concept of a "booth" any longer - merely a short barrier around 3 sides, the voter/assistant forming the 4th. It would be up to state law to determine how closely a monitor could, well, monitor. But for example, it's also possible that the assistants themselves will be assigned by the polling location, not by the voter.

In MA at least, the website for voters with disabilities says the voter can choose someone to assist them. But I suppose other states may do this differently.

@Barmar In IN, a voter is allowed to designate a relative or friend, but aren't required to do so. If they do, the assistant is required to fill out a form before assisting the voter. If they do not designate anyone, two assistants - one from each major political party - will be assigned to assist.

I think it was the 2022 election where I took my unsent (and un-filled-in) mail-in ballot to the polling place on election day and handed it in to vote in person instead.  It really confused the poll workers, but the option was right there in the instructions so they let me do it without considering it provisional.  But it does mean that I'd show up as having requested a mail-in ballot and voted in person.  Perfectly legal, but uncommon enough that I'm sure someone would (wrongly) consider it a sign of fraud.


Question:
Has there ever been a comprehensive audit of voter eligibility and identity in a U.S. election?

Answer:
Yes, they are conducted by the States and they are common.  Take this election.

Georgia (2024): In October 2024, Georgia's Secretary of State conducted an audit that identified 20 noncitizens among over 8.2 million registered voters. These registrations were canceled, and the individuals were referred for potential prosecution.


Raffensperger: audit finds noncitizens were only 1 in 400,000 registered Georgia voters
A state audit uncovered fewer than one in 400,000 registered voters in Georgia who were noncitizens, Republican Secretary of State Brad Raffensperger announced Wednesday at a press conference. The audit by Raffensper's office found just 20 noncitizens among more than 8.2 million registered voters.
“This is the most comprehensive citizenship check conducted in the history of Georgia, if not the most comprehensive check ever conducted in the United States of America,” Raffensperger said.


Ohio (2024): In September 2024, Ohio's Secretary of State identified 137 suspected noncitizens on the state's voter rolls out of approximately 8 million voters and initiated actions to confirm and remove them.


Secretary LaRose Announces Expanded Effort to Verify Citizenship Status on Ohio Voter Rolls


How exactly did they conduct this audit? Is there a detailed breakdown of the process involved?

@JonathanReez,  In Georgia's case they vetted the rolls of registered voters against state and federal databases.  But in every state the process is left up to the States who each run their own elections.  However, the Federal Government oversee's elections (FEC, DOJ) in each states sending officers to polling places and conducting their own reviews of state voting rolls.  In addition to this there are nonpartisan organizations which also conduct their own reviews (Brennan Center for Justice).

Right but that's a vague, handwavey answer. I want one that gives exact numbers for every step of the process. What databases were checked, exactly? What did they return for what % voters? What was done as a follow up as a result? Nobody wants to give any specifics, as if its highly classified information.

@JonathanReez probably because none exist.  It doesn't make sense to spend time, effort, and money quantifying a non-problem, so nobody has quantified it.

@phoog but they did do something? Georgia's Secretary of State conducted an audit that identified 20 noncitizens? All I want to know is what that something was...

@JonathanReez "The 20 individuals were found through affidavits they submitted to get out of jury duty, according to Gabriel Sterling, the chief operating officer within Raffensperger’s office, who also spoke at the press conference": all you have to do is click the link.  I would be a bit surprised if at least one of the 20 was actually a US citizen who lied about not being one to avoid jury duty, and the prosecution will end up being for perjury rather than illegal voting.

@phoog thanks - I could've clicked but comments are primarily intended as a critique of the answer, which should contain the core set of facts without having to click. So most comprehensive citizenship check conducted in the history of Georgia, if not the most comprehensive check ever conducted in the United States of America sounds like complete BS, if you pardon my French. It's the laziest for a citizenship check imaginable.

Following California's 46th congressional district election in 1996, a Congressional Committee investigated whether non-citizens had voted in the election.  (Among their many findings is that hundreds of non-citizens did in fact illegally vote.)  I believe you will find the report of the Task Force for The Contested Election in the 46th Congressional District of California [long text file] very interesting with regards to your desire for details of procedures and lots of numbers and discussion.
Another useful source of information about related issues is Contested Election Cases in the House of Representatives: 1933 to 2009 [55 page PDF].

The report of the Task Force for The Contested Election in the 46th Congressional District of California found that hundreds of noncitizens were registered to vote, which is very different from actually voting.  Much worse than this, however, the minority members note that the findings are based on seriously flawed methodology, including supposed name matches between INS records and the voting rolls where the names don't actually match, and one of the names belonged to a man and the other to a woman.

In case anyone is curious, Wikipedia's summary at present is as follows: "A 16-month Congressional investigation found some evidence that 624 votes were indeed cast illegally (of which 84 votes were cast by newly naturalized citizens on the actual date of the election who had registered before their naturalization, which is not allowed under California law)."  But perhaps anyone who doubts me or phoog should just read the report themselves.  In particular, the report includes "minority views".
